# JS strange mistake: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

Description of problem in code. Why it is going on??

```
var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
console.log(response[0].conversationUsers.length); //OK, console outputs "2"
  for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < response[i].conversationUsers.length; j++) { //Error 'cannot read property', but it has to be interpreted "j = 0; j < 2; j++" and it worked in console.log
          ...
        }
      }
```

UPD. I've added temporary variable and it works.

```
for (j = 0; j < response[i].conversationUsers.length; j++) //this way doesn't work

var temp = response[i].conversationUsers;
for (j = 0; j < temp.length; j++) //this way works
```

Question can be closed, but any ideas why so?

Comment: What is xhr.responseText

Comment: Response from one XmlHttpRequest. I received response as usual string, than parsed it into JSON format and saved to 'response'.

Comment: Evidently not all elements in the response have conversationUsers

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've checked response with console.log and all elements (there are ten ones) have conversationUsers

Comment: Can you share what the json looks like?

Comment: I don't know why, but when I added temporary variable, it began to work... 

var temp = response[i].conversationUsers;

So, when I call temp.length instead response[i].conversationUsers.length in 'for' cycle, it works without errors.

Comment: Since you're using global variables for `i` and `j`, I assume there's something inside the inner loop that's changing variable `i`. You should always use local variables for iterators (`for( var i = 0; ...`  or even better `for( let i = 0; ...`)

Comment: @JJJ I don't see problems with i and j, this ones are local. But I recognised that I have my error when put 'response[i].conversationUsers' in places with conditions as 'for' and 'if' directly. When I use temporary variable (see my edited post) it goes without errors, all data of JSON is visible.

Comment: You'll have to show the complete code, including where you define the variable.

Comment: @JJJ I’d guess that the OP isn’t actually defining the variables and doesn’t understand that without a `var`, `let`, or `const`, the variable actually gets defined globally. I was there once. So, @AlexeyBabanskyi if you aren’t using `i` or `j` anywhere else, you need to use one of those 3 keywords I said before, to scope the variable and not make it be global. It’s good practice and will help avoid bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `console.log()` for only the first object in that array. I suggest you try:

```
var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
  console.log(response[i].conversationUsers); // should be an array
  for (j = 0; j < response[i].conversationUsers.length; j++) {
          ...
  }
}
```

If you get any `undefined` in your console, while doing this, you have identified your problem.

The thing is that for the first element in the array `response[0].conversationUsers` has a value that is an array. That might not be true for every element in that array and therefore some of those elements might not have a length property.

Comment: I agree with this. Clearly `response` is an array of objects. Just because the first object has a conversationUsers key whose value is an array doesn’t mean the second or third or fourth one does. I don’t understand why you got downvoted. I’m upvoting this (bringing it to 0...). Maybe you’ll get more upvotes if you put together an answer that also contains what to do if your statement is correct, since currently it only helps debug the problem but doesn’t actually fix the issue. If you do that, also toss a `var` or `let` inside those `for` loops to demonstrate good code (I know you copied OP).

Answer (score -4):

You are trying to iterate inside length property. Try to remove length. Like this

```
    var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    console.log(response[0].conversationUsers.length);
    for (i = 0; i < response; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < response[i].conversationUsers; j++) {
          ...
      }
    }
```

Comment: You’re being downvoted by people because your answer is incorrect. You cannot compare a number to anything other than a number (you just said to do `0 < []`, basically). The middle condition needs to include `length` so that the loop compares two **numbers**. You should give your code a try before posting it. If you had, you’d see that it doesn’t work.